# GET or POST when reading request body

Tags: http, post, get

Should I use the GET or POST method when sending information to a server in the body of the HTTP request?  There are no query parameters appended to the URL, the server will inspect the body of the request for what it needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GET](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) extracts parameters from the request URL. [POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) extracts parameters from the request body.

So you need POST.

Answer (score 0):

A nice description and interesting discussion on the topic:

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/

Answer (score 0):

POST should be used if you are not planing on using the query string.

Comment: POST can still pass query string args.

Comment: it can, but the browser will not generate the query string based on the form in a POST but will in a GET.