# Spring MVC - Is it possible to receive a strongly typed request object on a GET?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller which is servicing GET requests, to perform a search.

These requests have many optional parameters which may be passed on the query string.

For example:

```
@Data
public class SimpleSearchRequest implements SearchRequest {

    private String term;
    private List<Status> stati;
    @JsonDeserialize(using=DateRangeDeserializer.class)
    private Range<DateTime> dateRange;  
}
```

If I were using a POST or PUT for this, I could nicely marshall the inbound request using a `@RequestBody`.  However, because I'm using a GET, this doesn't seem to fit.

Instead, it seems I'm required to list all the possible parameters on the method signature as `@RequestParam(required=false)`.

Aside from leading to ugly method signatures, I'm also losing out on all sorts of OO goodness by not using classes here.

Attempting to use `@RequestBody` fails (understandably so), and as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270708/spring-resttemplate-http-get-with-request-body) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body), using an actual request body on a GET is not desirable.

Is there a way to get Spring MVC to support marshalling multiple `@RequestParam`'s to a strongly typed object on GET requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer was to simply remove the annotation.

This worked:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Result> search(SearchRequest request) {}
```