# Pass JSON as Java Class to Spring Controller by GET

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, get

I have the following code that works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jsonasclass", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
ContactVO jsonAsClassPost(@RequestBody ContactVO ct){
    ct.setFirstName("This-property-is-changed-in-the-controller");
    return ct;
}
```

and the corresponding ajax call by post:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/jsonasclass/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                  id:1,
                  userID:1.1, 
                  login:'sample-login',
                  firstName:'sample-first-name'
                }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            mimeType: 'application/json',
            success: _callBack,
            error: _errorCallback
        });
```

Now I want to achieve the same thing, but I want to do it by GET. Anyone knows how?

- I have tried changing POST to GET (in both controller and ajax call) but it did not work.
- The error I get: description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: Try changing to 'GET' in ajax call and in @RequestMapping 'method' attribute  as well

Comment: Yes, I changed in both places. But it did not work.

Comment: Use Firebug to track the GET request

Comment: yes, I tried all of the standard methods. I get this error: description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: Either it is clearly a build/compilation problem or you have another method mapped with the same url with different HttpMethod type. Try clean and create a new build

Comment: There is no build/compilation problem. The `HTTP GET` is not meant to work that way (passing content on the request). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270708/spring-resttemplate-http-get-with-request-body) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).
The common way to pass parameters to a `GET` is via URL parameters.

Comment: @RaulRene `data` is actually [appended to the URI for GET requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: When you changed the method to GET did you also change the `@RequestBody` parameter?

Comment: @Floegipoky Yes, but you append **strings**, not objects to the URL. He should pass `id`, `userId`, etc as strings and retrieve them using the `@PathVariable` or `@RequestParam` annotations

Comment: He is using `contentType: 'application/json'`, which is telling the server: *hey, I'm sending you a JSON*

Comment: RaulRene's comment actually helped. I figured out how to do it from his comment. Thanks :) I will post the answer soon.

Comment: @RaulRene I'll be the first to admit that my js knowledge isn't exactly top-notch, but isn't that what `JSON.stringify` is for, converting the json to a string?  As I implied in my last comment though, I agree that the `@RequestBody` probably won't work for GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to RaulRene's comment here is how you would do it.

- get rid of @RequestBody from the controller and change method to get.
- send the properties of the class in the controller as browser variables and spring will automatically map them to the class.

Here is the solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jsonasclass", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
ContactVO jsonAsClassGet(ContactVO  ct){
    ct.setFirstName("This-property-is-changed-in-the-controller");
    return ct;
}
```

and corresponding ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'/jsonasclass/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
              id:1,
              userID:1.1, 
              login:'sample-login',
              firstName:'sample-first-name'
            },
        success: _callBack,
        error: _errorCallback
    });
```

Comment: BTW, make sure that the class you are accepting as a parameter and the class you are returning implements Serializable.