# Spring RestTemplate passing the type of the response

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I am using Spring RestTemplate to make a GET call with a request body.

So I am making a bunch of web service calls using the rest template. For each one of them they support getting a resource passing a query as a request body parameter. I am using the following to pass the body :

```
 Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<String, String>();
 requestBody.put("type", "Sandwich");
 requestBody.put("flavor", "blueberry");
 MultiValueMap<String, Map<String, String>> body = constructQueries(requestBody); //see below
 HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(body, headers);
 ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://myurl.com/ids", HttpMethod.GET, request, type);
```

I am constructing the body as follows:

```
private MultiValueMap<String, Map<String, String>> constructQueries(Map<String, String> pBody){
    MultiValueMap<String, Map<String, String>> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    //List<Map<String, String>> queryLists = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : pBody.entrySet())
    {
        Map<String, String> singleQuery = new HashMap<String, String>();
        singleQuery.put("field", entry.getKey());
        singleQuery.put("value", entry.getValue());
        body.add("query", singleQuery);                 
    }

    return body;
}
```

My body (in JSON) is supposed to look like this:

```
{ "query": [ { "field" : "type", "value": "Sandwich" } , { "field" : "flavor", "value": "blueberry" }] }
```

But when I look at the server side received request, the body is not passed at all. Does rest template not support passing body for GET calls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring RestTemplate - http GET with request body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270708/spring-resttemplate-http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: _the body is not passed at all_ OR it's not passed like you expected? What's in the request your server receives, _specifically_?

Comment: No body is not passed at all. Server sees the header. Body is null.

Comment: What header values are there?

Comment: I am passing Content-Type as application/json in the base class, so that is there. headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Comment: I believe that `RestTemplate` uses a `FormHttpMessageConverter` for `MultiValueMap` values. Can you instead try to use a Pojo type for your body?

Comment: Can you may be point to a link or example how to translate a MultiValueMap to Pojo?