# Converting request parameters to the Class object

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I have two POJO classes.

Class 1 is **Engine.java**:

```
private String engineId;

public String getEngineId(){
  return this.engineId;
}   

public void setEngineId(String engineId){
  this.engineId = engineId;
}
```

The Second POJO class is **Vehicle.java**:

```
private String type;
private String manufacturer;
private Engine engine;

public String getType() {
   return type;
} 

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
} 

public String getManufacturer() {
     return manufacturer;
} 

public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
     this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}  

public Engine getEngine() {
     return engine;
} 

public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}
```

I have a REST Controller for providing information of Vechicles (RequestMethod.GET):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Vehicle getVechileDetails(Vehicle inputVehicle){
   Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
    // some processing
    return vehicle;
}
```

When I hit this service and provide the Request parameter as type or manufacturer, then the Spring creates the Vehicle object and populates the value of type and manufacturer. But if I provide the value of engineId, then the Spring is not able to create the Engine object such that `vehicle.getEngine().getEngineId() != null`

Is there any way in which if I invoke my Rest Service like:

```
http://localhost:8080/Controller/getVehicleDetails?engineId=12345
```

then the Vehicle is created with Engine having the value of engineId ?

Comment: Kindly add spring bean config for both the beans.

Comment: Why do we require Spring Bean configuration in this case ? If defining the bean (injecting engine to vehicle) on application startup can help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the vehicleId like this (ResponseEntity structure is included):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Controller/getVehicleDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<AjaxResponse> controller(@RequestParam(value = "engineId") Long engineId) {
        //Do whatever you want with the engineId
        return new ResponseEntity<AjaxResponse>(new AjaxResponse("Success"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But, for POJOs, I have to warn two things:

1. Make sure your classes implement `Serializable`
2. For the fields which are not certain while converting from Java to Javascript or vice versa, like `Date` variables, You have to set your JsonSerializer class properly

**Update:** You wanted to get the object from request, so:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Controller/getVehicleDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<AjaxResponse> controller(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
        //vehicle.getEngine().getEngineId()
        return new ResponseEntity<AjaxResponse>(new AjaxResponse("Success"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

POJOS:

```
    public class Engine implements Serializable {
        //...
    }

    public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
        private Engine engine;
    }
```

JS side:

```
    var vehicle = {
        engine: {id: 123}//,
        //...
    }
    //via angularjs:
    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/Controller/getVehicleDetails", vehicle).success(function(response) {
        console.log("success");
    });
```

Comment: The problem is not how can i get engineId as an Input Parameter. The problem is I want Vehicle Object as the Input Parameter, even if the user hits the service by passing the engineId.

Comment: Do you want to get it as object from the request?

Comment: Yes. I want the Vehicle object populated with the engineId, such that : `vehicle.getEngine().getEngineId()` should give me the value.

Comment: you changed the RequetMethod from GET to POST. :) Need the Vehicle object as an input parameter where the request type is GET.

Comment: If you are posting an object at the request body, you have to set it to POST

Comment: I understand what you are saying. So it means there is no way in which we can send the Object with Request.GET method ?

Comment: Yes, please read this naswer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13270939/1201725 and don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one

Comment: Thank you. The link you have provided helps !

Answer (score 0):

Here you can refer , where the request body has JSON  which converted to Object 
See : [For references](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-rest-example-tutorial-spring-restful-web-services)

```
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.CREATE_EMP, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
        logger.info("Start createEmployee.");
        emp.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        empData.put(emp.getId(), emp);
        return emp;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is with the `RequestMethod.GET`. Can't use @RequestBody with GET.