# How to attach a body to a GET request when using Spring's new RestClient?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, client

I am writing a client using java and spring framework which will send a get request with body (I am aware that it is not recommended but it is not my decision) to the server using RestClient

I am aware that a similar question already exists ([Spring RestTemplate - http GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270708/spring-resttemplate-http-get-with-request-body)) but it is implemented using RestTemplate and in my case I am using the new RestClient.

I have tried searching and experimenting but to no avail as there isn't much information regarding RestClient yet. I have an error when I try to add the .body() to the .get(). It works fine for post requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use .method() with the desired http method type and then add the body here is the code:

```
restClient.method(HttpMethod.GET).body("your body")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).